# Custom validation rule not applying

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I want to add a custom validation rule in a model that checks if at least one of two fields is not empty. For simplicity, I've reduce validations to this

```
public $validate = array(
    'first' => array(
        'oneEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxOneEmpty', 'second'),
            'message' => 'At least one must be filled'
        )
    ),
    'second' => array(
        'oneEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxOneEmpty', 'first'),
            'message' => 'At least one must be filled'
        )
    )
```

There's other validations in place, and those work fine (none of those dependent of another field, though). Now, this doesn't validate. I've even modified the custom function to

```
public function maxOneEmpty($check, $notEmptyToo) {
    return false;
}
```

with no luck. If I try to save the model (intentionally making a bad validation so it doesn't actually save), I get this when doing `$this->Model->validationErrors` in the controller

```
Array
(
    [House] => Array
        (
            [third] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Enter a valid option
                )
        )
)
```

when clearly `first` and `second` should be errors too. So the model is validating, just not those fields.

This happens if I don't put any values on the `first` and `second` field. If I put anything on the `first` field, it validates the custom function (giving me false because of the return). But this isn't useful to me, I need to be able to check if at least one of the fields has a value, but if both are empty (and when the actual validation should return false) it doesn't even try to validate. I've tried adding `required => true` to the rules, but no luck. Doesn't make sense to add `allowEmpty => false` so I didn't even tried that.

The other option I can think of is to add a function that checks that "validation" in the model's `beforeSave`, but I'd like to be able to do it with validations (so I don't have to mess with the validations array to output the error message like I want it to).

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong... I'm saving two models with `saveAll`, but the problem persist even if I do a simple `save`. The resulting array of the posted form being

```
Array
(
    [House] => Array
        (
            [first] => 
            [second] => 
            [third] => t
        )
)
```

in case it's of any help. Not sure what other info could be useful here, but let me know. Thanks in advance.

(Using cakephp 2.4.4)

Answer (score 1):

Setting `required => true` only means that the array key has to be present; it doesn't check the value at all.

Try the following code:

```
public $validate = array(
    'first' => array(
        'oneEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxOneEmpty'),
         'message' => 'At least one must be filled'
        )
    ),
    'second' => array(
        'oneEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxOneEmpty'),
            'message' => 'At least one must be filled'
        )
    )
);

public function maxOneEmpty() {
    if ((empty($this->data['Model']['first'])) && (empty($this->data['Model']['second']))) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, it still doesn't validate when `first` and `second` are empty :(  Thought the removal of variables in the function might do the trick even if it made it un-reutilizable, but no, the same result...

Comment: Weird. I just tested it on my site and it worked fine (after I corrected parentheses to match the edit above). Leaving `first` and `second` blank results in an error message saying **"At least one must be filled"** on both fields. Filling in either one validates the form.

Comment: It seems weird to me too, that's why I posted the question. Your answer looks ok and I thought it would work, but no... Is there a configuration I'm missing? I don't think so, but maybe? I'll update the question if I get more info on the problem...